# Unable to link two "sidecar" containers in my Jenkins pipeline

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, docker, jenkins-pipeline

Currently, I am hitting an external DB to carry out unit tests in my pipeline. I want to increase runtime of the build by implementing local testing within the pipeline.

I'm attempting to use [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers) format.

```py
docker.image('mysql:5.6').withRun(' -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass" ') { c ->

    sh('docker ps -l')

    docker.image('mysql:5.6').inside(" --link ${c.id}:db ") {

        /* Wait until mysql service is up */
        sh ("while ! mysqladmin ping -hdb:3306 -ppass; do sleep 1; done")

    }

    docker.image(imageName).inside(" --link ${c.id}:db ") {
        /*
        * Run some tests which require MySQL, and assume that it is
        * available on the host name `db`
        */
        sh("echo test")
        //run some tests        
    }
}
```

The code doesn't reach the second image. It errors out before because it `can't connect to the host 'db'`. Here is the output:

```sh
+ docker run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass mysql:5.6
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintRun
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
63c18d0dfbd6        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint..."   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second   3306/tcp            sleepy_haibt2
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . mysql:5.6
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
slave-37188a47f08d1 seems to be running inside container 5e34252...
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ mysqladmin ping -hdb:3306 -ppass
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'db:3306' failed
error: 'Unknown MySQL server host 'db:3306' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running on db:3306 and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet db:3306 3306'
+ sleep 1
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 --link 63c18d0d...:db -w /home/jenkins/workspace/-database-for-testing-in-jenkins --volumes-from 5e34252... -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** mysql:5.6 cat
$ docker top d003b0649... -eo pid,comm
+ mysqladmin ping -hdb:3306 -ppass
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'db:3306' failed
error: 'Unknown MySQL server host 'db:3306' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running on db:3306 and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet db:3306 3306'
+ sleep 1
```

I've tried removing `:3306` from `mysqladmin`

I've tried adding `-p 3306:3306` to both the main container and the sidecar mysql container.

I've tried adding `-u 0` to to both the containers.

`Docker Version 18.09`

`Jenkins Version 2.164`

`K8s Version 1.11`

**Not sure what to do next. Advice?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong here, but ended up using `withRun` for the first sidecar and `docker exec` to run the ping. That fixed it.